# Type mismatch in Android for FragmentTransaction with getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()

Tags: android, fragment, fragmenttransaction

when i try replace the Fragment by declare FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction() in an activity, i always has the following error alert:

[image]

```
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;

    public class MainFrameActivity extends ActivitySupport {

    FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

    switch (position) {
    case 0:
        ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragmentDiscover);
        break;
    case 1:
        ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragmentPersonInfo);
        break;
    }

    ft.commit();

    mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);

    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
}
```

and the class is ActivitySupport inherited from:

```
public class ActivitySupport extends Activity implements IActivitySupport {
```

I've tried to change the getFragmentManager to getSupportFragmentManager(), and it's getting even worse to have the alert the method is not undefined.

So what can i do to make the getFragmentManager() to be a v4 supported method?

Comment: Check whether you've imported the right FragmentTransaction class (i.e., support lib vs. core OS). That's really the only thing I could see being an issue.

Comment: i'm not sure but it should have a method like `getSupportFragmentManager()`..

Comment: That, too. Don't have the docs in front of me, so the asker will have to check.

Comment: you need to extend FragmentActivity for the ActivitySupport class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First extend `FragmentActivity` and make sure you are using the one from the support library.

Try using `getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()` instead of `getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()`.

The problem is that you have imported FragmentTransaction from v4 support library and you are not using the fragment manager from the v4 support library.

[Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.html) is the link for further refrence.

Hope this helps  : )

Comment: Thank you Ankit, Thank you for your great support and clue, it really works.

Answer (score 4):

Change it

```
public class ActivitySupport extends Activity implements IActivitySupport {
```

***To***

```
public class ActivitySupport extends FragmentActivity implements IActivitySupport {
```

**and then it will work**

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
```

Comment: Thank you Amit, your answer severed very good for me, and this is worked.